# How to make a total and Grouping a report

Tags: crystal-reports, group-by, grouping

Using Crystal Report 8.5

Generating a report from table1

My Crystal Report Output

```
ID Name Date Totaltime 

001 Raja 23/02/2009 08:00:00 
001 Raja 24/02/2009 10:00:00 
001 Raja 25/02/2009 09:00:00 
001 Raja 26/02/2009 11:00:00 
001 Raja 27/02/2009 07:00:00 
002 Ravi 23/02/2009 11:00:00 
002 Ravi 24/02/2009 10:00:00 
002 Ravi 25/02/2009 10:00:00 
002 Ravi 26/02/2009 12:00:00 
002 Ravi 27/02/2009 14:00:00 
…,
```

TotalTime Column Format – (HH:MM:SS)

ID Column Data type - varchar
Name Colum Data type – varchar
Date Column Data type – date time
Totaltime Column Date type – varchar

In the output report I want to make a Total of TotalTime Column for each personid

Expected Ouput

I want to make a report in below mentioned format

```
ID Name Date TotalTime

001 Raja

23/02/2009 08:00:00 
24/02/2009 10:00:00 
25/02/2009 09:00:00 
26/02/2009 11:00:00
27/02/2009 07:00:00

TotalTime  45 Hours    or (45:00:00)                                           

002 Ravi

23/02/2009 110000 
24/02/2009 100000 
25/02/2009 100000 
26/02/2009 120000 
27/02/2009 140000 

TotalTime  57 Hours or (57:00:00)
…,
```

How to create a formula for getting a total time and grouping a report in this Format?

Need Formula and above mentioned Report Format Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Sum the time(hh:mm:ss format ) field in a group in Crystal Report?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1401755.aspx)